# how to interface ultrasonic sensor hc-sr04 with easyPic v7 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, sensors

Good evening guys!

Is there anyone who have an idea about how to interface ultrasonic sensor with pic microcontroller easyPic v7 with PIC18F45K22 chip, in order to make person counter.

I found a useful code and I tried to edit it but still it's not working...

Here is my code:

```
// Lcd module connections
sbit LCD_RS at LATB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at LATB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at LATB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at LATB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at LATB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at LATB3_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;

void main()
{
  int a;
  Lcd_Init();
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);

  Lcd_Out(1,5,"ITCE444");
  Lcd_Out(2,3,"Term Project");

  Delay_ms(3000);
  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);

  TRISA.RA0 = 0;  //RB0 as Input PIN (TRG)
  TRISA.RA4 = 0;  //RB4 as Input PIN (ECHO)

  while(1)
  {
    if(PORTA.RA4==1 && PORTA.RA0==1)
    {
      a = a + 1;
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Person in: ");
      Lcd_Out(1,12,a);
      Lcd_Out(1,15,"Person");
    }
    else
    {
      a = a - 1;
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Person out: ");
      Lcd_Out(1,13,a);
    }
    Delay_ms(400);
  }
}
```

Thanks and regards..

Comment: Any help, please....

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted above is 100% incorrect. [Here is](https://electrosome.com/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-pic/) how the code is supposed to look like.

`HC-SR04` is an ultrasonic **distance** sensor. It measures the distance between the sensor and an obstacle. While you can definitely use the distance information to make a counter, it seems like that is a little above your skillset.

So have three options:

1. Learn to use pic micro-controllers and write a lot of *timer* code
   to get the distance reading from the sensor.
2. Switch to Arduino and use it's builtin libraries to get the
   distance.
3. Change your hardware. You do not need an ultrasonic sensor (or a
   microcontroller for that matter) to make a person counter. I suggest
   you simply use a pair of infrared leds to make yourself a simple
   circuit that gives a pulse when a person walks though them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply **Mr Hassan Nadeem**, I have an update for the code and it's almost work when I implemented it.

Have a look and tell me what you think:

```
// LCD module connections
sbit LCD_RS at LATB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at LATB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at LATB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at LATB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at LATB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at LATB3_bit;
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISB4_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISB5_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISB0_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISB1_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISB2_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISB3_bit;
// End LCD module connections

// Ultrasonic module connection
sbit Ultrasonic at RD0_bit;
sbit Ultrasonic_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
// End of Ultrasonic module connections

#define Pole_Height 200

void main()
{
   unsigned long Tm;
   unsigned char Tl, Th;
   unsigned int h, Person_Height,dist;

   char Txt[7];

   int cont =0 ;

   ANSELB = 0;
   ANSELD = 0;

   Lcd_Init();
   Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
   Lcd_Out(2,3,"Term Project");
   Lcd_Out(1,5,"ITCE444");
   Delay_Ms(2000);T0CON = 0x00;

   for(;;)
   {
      Ultrasonic_Direction = 0;
      TMR0H = 0;
      TMR0L = 0;

      Ultrasonic = 0;
      Delay_us(3);
      Ultrasonic = 1;
      Delay_us(10);
      Ultrasonic = 0;

      while(PORTD.RD5 == 0);
         T0CON.TMR0ON = 1;
      while(PORTD.RD5 == 1);
         T0CON.TMR0ON = 0;

      Tl = TMR0L;
      Th = TMR0H;
      Tm = Th*256 + Tl;
      Tm = Tm / 2;
      Tm = 34 * Tm;
      Tm = Tm / 1000;
      h = (unsigned int)Tm;
      Person_Height= Pole_Height - h;

      if (Person_Height > 168 && Person_Height < 196)
         cont = cont + 1 ;
      else if(Person_Height > 132 && Person_Height < 160 && cont>0)
         cont = cont - 1 ;

      IntToStr(cont, Txt);

      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Out(1,1, "Person in");
      Lcd_Out(2,1, Txt);
      Delay_Ms(1000);
   }
}
```